# Is it possible for android app to communicate with apache local host running on PC ?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Android to talk to Apache on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394439/getting-android-to-talk-to-apache-on-localhost)

Hi i have written a application to post image to server, but currently the server public IP is not yet hosted, because of this i am not able to test my features.

But i have one question i have the server code in my local apache server which run's fine on PC, now i want my android app in device to communicate with this local host (my local website).

i have wifi router is it possible to communicate with this..
if so please let me know configuration details and any changes i need to do for 
URL in code. to point to local host.

Answer (score 0):

You should use IP in local network that points to pc with exposed apache server (if you're using WAMP switch it online). You can test your URL and apache service availability through another pc that is connected to local network.
Another option is to run app on emulator and use localhost address: 10.0.2.2 [127.0.0.1 for android emulators].